# Can't install phpmyadmin 4.4.9

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've always been using an old version of PMA, i just downloaded the latest version 4.4.9 and i can't log in, it says "Cannot log in to the MySQL server". I have followed the instructions in the doc, i've created the "config" directory, placed inside it "config.inc.php" file, and the first problem is that this file is not being changed after I make changes in the setup page, is there something i'm missing out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When making changes in the setup script, you have to explicitly select "Save" which is on the Overview page; so normally you'll make a change on one of the other pages, press Apply, then the Overview page loads...then you have to press Save at the bottom of that page to write the settings to the file.

[image: Save dialog]

Additionally, just a reminder that you'll have to move the file out of the `config` directory once you're done with the setup script for phpMyAdmin to read it.

Comment: Thanks Isaac for your time. according to @Terna, i need to be using Mysql 5.5, which is not my case :/

Comment: That is true, as indicated in the Requirements section of the documentation, but is not the reason your configuration changes don't get saved. If you check the Download tab at http://www.phpmyadmin.net you can see the latest version available for older MySQL versions, which currently is 4.0.10.10. Good luck.

Comment: You were right Isaac, I had to click on "Save", i thought it was enough to click on "Apply" :)
I'll try other version of PMA that works with my MySQL version
Thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

I experienced also that problem.
are you sure you are using correct localhost name? use the default localhost name and password

Comment: Thanks Ralph for your answer. As i'm on a managed dedicated server with 1&1, i'm using "localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock" for the host name, that's what i was using with the previous version...
But why the setup page isn't making any changes to the config file?

Comment: Actually, since you have a socket instead of hostname, you should put the path in to the socket directive as such: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/tmp/mysql5.sock';`

Comment: Hi Isaac, thanks for your reply. I did for the moment set only the host: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock';` isn't that enough?

Comment: Hi again, I managed to install the latest version of PMA: 4.6.4, and i noticed a db named pma created within my db, what is that for??

Answer (score 0):

You should be using MYSQL 5.5 or higher to use the latest phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thanks Terna for tour reply. I have just checked the version of mysql, and it's 5.1 :( so i guess i wont be able to run the latest version og PMA!!